# Android : Unable to preview video recorded during authoring

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera-intent, android-video-record

I am using a video recording intent structure during Android development. I transfer the video I recorded to a cloud application.I use the video recording interface provided by Android, not a special interface. On some devices, when I press the preview button of the video I recorded, the recording is closed and deleted. What should I do ?

Edit:

```
  public void OpenVideoCamera(){
         if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(fragment_activity, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(fragment_activity, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(fragment_activity, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
 PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                 ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(fragment_activity,Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
 != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)  {
             AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(fragment_activity);
             alertBuilder.setCancelable(true);
             alertBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.permission_required_text));
             alertBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.camera_permission_text).replace("{0}",
 getString(R.string.application_name)));
             alertBuilder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     requestPermissions(new String[] {   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                     Manifest.permission.CAMERA,
                                     Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
                                     Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE },
                             PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_VID_UPLOAD);
                 }
             });
             AlertDialog alert = alertBuilder.create();
             alert.show();
             //sneaker.warning(getString(R.string.require_permission));
         } else {
             StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
             StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
             String temp_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/" +
 getString(R.string.application_name) + "/temp";
             File temp_folder = CommonFeaturesController.getCommonFeaturesInstance().setFilePermissionFromFile(new
 File(temp_path));
             try {
                 if (!temp_folder.exists()) {
                     if (CommonFeaturesController.getCommonFeaturesInstance().isAuthorized())
                         temp_folder.mkdirs();
                 }
             } catch (Exception e) {
             }
             mediaFile = CommonFeaturesController.getCommonFeaturesInstance().setFilePermissionFromFile(new
 File(temp_path, "VIDEO_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
 + ".mp4"));
             Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
             takeVideoIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(mediaFile));
             if (takeVideoIntent.resolveActivity(getContext().getPackageManager()) !=
 null) {
                 startActivityForResult(takeVideoIntent, CAMERA_VID_REQUEST);
                 CommonFeaturesController.getCommonFeaturesInstance().setIsExternalIntent(true);
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should post all the relevant code so we can assess what's happening.

Comment: Even though I have all the permissions required, it turns off when I save the media and press the preview button.
I added the code as a comment

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Please refrain from posting it as an answer if it doesn't actually answer your question. You can always edit your original post to include additional information. I did that for you this time so don't worry about it. Is there any exception you're getting or is your app crashing at the same time?  The logcat would also be useful here.

Comment: The *`preview button`* is not part of your app, is it?

Comment: Thank you @NikosHidalgo. 
The application does not crash. While you can play it smoothly on some devices, it turns off directly on some devices. The application works fine, but the video recorder is lost.

Comment: @AlexCohn preview button is not part of my app

Comment: *`on some devices`* – the community deserves to know the names (the model and the OS version).

Comment: This could be a device-specific bug. Try to install an alternative camera app, e.g. [Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera&hl=en) and see for yourself if the problem is reproduced when you choose this app to fulfill the `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent.

Comment: @AlexCohn thats true. Xiaomi Note 8 Android 10 .